# Get the data that doesn't exists in database

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Firstly... I would like to apologize if my question looks silly

Is there anyway we can get the data that doesn't exits in database... To be more specific my requirement is to get the `Dates` for whole month but my database has only dates for few days in a month.

Now what I need is to get the all dates in a month though database doesn't has the data.

Database has the records:

```
01/01/2014
01/02/2014
01/05/2014
01/24/2014
```

My requirement is:

```
01/01/2014
01/02/2014
01/03/2014
01/04/2014
01/05/2014
01/06/2014
.
.
.
.
.
01/24/2014
.
.
.

01/31/2014
```

I am not getting any idea on where to start.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a hierarchical CONNECT BY + dual table to generate the data you need:

```
/*
WITH tab AS 
(
  SELECT to_date('01/01/2014', 'MM/DD/YYYY') dates FROM dual
  UNION ALL SELECT to_date('01/02/2014', 'MM/DD/YYYY') dates FROM dual
  UNION ALL SELECT to_date('01/05/2014', 'MM/DD/YYYY') dates FROM dual
  UNION ALL SELECT to_date('01/24/2014', 'MM/DD/YYYY') dates FROM dual  
)
*/ 
SELECT to_date('01/01/2014', 'MM/DD/YYYY') + lvl 
FROM (SELECT LEVEL - 1 lvl FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 31) mock_tab
     LEFT JOIN tab ON dates = to_date('01/01/2014', 'MM/DD/YYYY') + lvl
ORDER BY 1;
```

`SELECT LEVEL - 1 lvl FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 31` generates numbers from 0 to 30 in a column `lvl` (`level` is an Oracle pseudo column indicating the level of the hierarchy). This is a common way to generate sequences of numbers.

`to_date('01/01/2014', 'MM/DD/YYYY') + lvl` gives you the dates from '01/01/2014' to '01/31/2014'

The logic:

1) Generate the required dates in a `mock_tab`

2) Left join `mock_tab` with the target table on date field column

Comment: Thanks for your reply... your answer is working but can you please explain me the logic.

Comment: @Siva I've added some extra info in my answer

Answer (score 1):

You could create a column of dates independend of table content like this:

```
SELECT dateval
 FROM 
    (SELECT (trunc(sysdate, 'MM')  + rownum) -1 dateval FROM dual 
    CONNECT BY rownum < 31 )
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.... your solution is also working can you please explain me the logic

Comment: Maybe this explains the logic `SELECT a,b,c FROM ( select rownum -1 a, sysdate b, sysdate+rownum-1 c FROM dual CONNECT BY rownum < 31) `. It is just a list of numbers. Date plus integer adds a days in oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Dates in Oracle are actually decimal numbers, and the unity is : one day. Thing is, he never displays them this way. But, once you know this, it's easy to create cursors with some number added or subtracted from it. Example : you want to know all records from the last 30 days, even if not all days have corresponding data ? Start with "where trunc(date_column) = trunc (sysdate) -30, then do the same : trunc (sysdate) -29, then with -28, and so on and on. You can display the actual date, even when trunced (because only the time is "truncated" to midnight, the day remains the same).